# app.post connection and middleware in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

app.post is not working on postman and showing result in not in JSON format and also middleware is showing error in postman what m doing wrong in this??
is there any new middleware code introduced recently??

```
// importing
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Messages from "./dbMessages.js";

//app config
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

//middleware
app.use(express.json());

//DB config
const connection_url =
  "mongodb+srv://admin:0ZKon3XRmT0SWkal@cluster0.7pljv.mongodb.net/whatsappdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose.connect(connection_url, {
  // useCreateIndex: true,
  // useNewUrlParser: true,
  // useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

//????

//api routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("hello world"));


app.post("/messages/new", (req, res) => {
  const dbMessage = req.body;

  Messages.create(dbMessage, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(201).send(data);
    }
  });
});

//listen
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on localhost:${port}`));
```

`dbmessages.js is given below`

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const whatsappSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  message: String,
  name: String,
  timestamp: String,
  received: Boolean,
});

export default mongoose.model("messageContent", whatsappSchema);
```

Comment: Can you add the error you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating the instance of a model.

```
app.post("/messages/new", (req, res) => {
  const dbMessage = req.body,
        messageModel = new Messages();

  message.Modelmessage = req.body.Modelmessage;
  message.Modelname = req.body.Modelname;
  messageModel.timestamp = req.body.timestamp;
  messageModel.received = req.body.received;
 
  messageModel.save().then(data => {
     res.status(201).send(data);
  }).catch((e) => {
     res.status(500).send(err);
  })

     

});
```